# PGLOADER error sqlite3.dll but am not using sqlite

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use pgloader for Postgresql on Windows, downloaded from http://pgloader.io/.

The reason I'm trying to use pgloader rather than COPY is that I want to do imports from delimited files with subsets of the columns from the source files to be inserted (rather than all), and in some cases, conversions from strings to dates at insertion based on the source format (or one data type to another in general).

I am having trouble getting pgloader to work at all, let alone do what I want it to do. I started by trying to get a simple load working.

I am running postgresql 9.3 portable on Windows.

I've created a test table called `fish` in the `public` schema, the database is called `test`.

```
create table fish (
    fish_id    int,
    fish_descr varchar(20)
);
```

On my computer I have a file called `more_fish.txt` with 2 rows:

```
2|Sooodles
3|Poodles
```

(it is pipe delimited).

I want to insert those 2 rows into the `fish` table.

Running the following `COPY` works as intended and inserts the 2 rows:

```
copy fish FROM 'C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\more_fish.txt' delimiter '|';
```

So as to ensure I have the basics of pgloader down before attempting format conversions at insertion I am trying to just get the above example working using pgloader.

I am running the following in the command line (I am using Windows):

```
cd C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin
pgloader commands.load
```

The `commands.load` file is in that bin folder (as well as pgloader.exe) and contains the following:

```
LOAD CSV  
   FROM 'C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\more_fish.txt' WITH ENCODING iso-646-us  
        HAVING FIELDS  
        (  
           fish_id, fish_descr
        )  
   INTO postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/test?fish
        TARGET COLUMNS
        (  
           fish_id, fish_descr
        )  
   WITH truncate,  
        skip header = 0,  
        fields terminated by '|'

    SET work_mem to '32 MB', maintenance_work_mem to '64 MB';
```

The above uses one of the examples in the pgloader documentation just modified for what I thought would be an easy test.

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop>cd C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin

C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin>pgloader commands.load

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {26922DB9}>:
  Error opening shared object "sqlite3.dll":
 The specified module could not be found.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE       ] Skip this shared object and continue.
  1: [RETRY          ] Retry loading this shared object.
  2: [CHANGE-PATHNAME] Specify a different pathname to load the shared object from.
0

(SB-SYS:DLOPEN-OR-LOSE #S(SB-ALIEN::SHARED-OBJECT :PATHNAME #P"sqlite3.dll" :NAMESTRING "sqlite3.dll" :HANDLE NIL :DONT-SAVE NIL))
0]
```

I don't see why I am getting an error re: sqlite. I did not specify that as a source database in any way.

Does anyone know how to do this very basic COPY using pgloader: (or why I'm getting the above error when running the above)

```
copy fish FROM 'C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\more_fish.txt' delimiter '|';
```

User: postgres
Port: default 5432
Database name: test
Table name: fish
Schema: public

**Edit based on comments**

Running `pgloader --verbose commands.load` had no impact.

I tried putting sqlite3.dll into the bin folder, result changed to this:

```
C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop>cd C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin

C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin>pgloader --verbose commands.load

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {26922DB9}>:
  Error opening shared object "libeay32.dll":
 %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE       ] Skip this shared object and continue.
  1: [RETRY          ] Retry loading this shared object.
  2: [CHANGE-PATHNAME] Specify a different pathname to load the shared object from.
0

(SB-SYS:DLOPEN-OR-LOSE #S(SB-ALIEN::SHARED-OBJECT :PATHNAME #P"libeay32.dll" :NAMESTRING "libeay32.dll" :HANDLE NIL :DONT-SAVE NIL))
0]
```

Tried downloading `libeay32.dll` from https://openvpn.net/release/openssl/ and putting it into the bin folder, result changed to:

[image]
    C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop>cd C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin

```
C:\Users\ShWiVeL\Desktop\postgresql\postgresql\PostgreSQLPortable\App\PgSQL\bin>pgloader --verbose commands.load

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {26922DB9}>:
  Problem running initialization hook #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()
                                                   :IN
                                                   "//vboxsrv/vagrant/src/hooks.lisp")
                                        {2275BA15}>:
  Unable to load foreign library (LIBSSL).
  Error opening shared object "libssl32.dll":
 The specified procedure could not be found.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Skip this initialization hook.
0

(SB-INT:CALL-HOOKS "initialization" (#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN "//vboxsrv/vagrant/src/hooks.lisp") {2275BA15}> SB-BSD-SOCKETS-INTERNAL::CALL-WSA-STARTUP SB-WIN32::INITIALIZE-CONSOLE-CONTROL-HANDLER) :ON-ERROR :ERROR)
0]
```

(`libssl32.dll` is and was already in the bin folder)

Comment: try running pgloader with --verbose command line switch and post any additional output or maybe just download sqlite3.dll and drop it in the same dir as pgloader to get past this error.

Comment: it appears from http://pgloader.io/download.html that the windows version is experimental so it might not be "fully baked".  You can try getting help directly from the author Dimitri Fontaine http://tapoueh.org/about or looking at the postgresql forums http://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&q=pgloader or even posting/moving this question on/to the StackExchange dba forum.

Comment: You might also want to try a "real" Postgres version rather than this "portable" thing.